# 'undefined is not an object' when using ImageBackground React Native

Tags: react-native

I receive the error 'undefined is not an object (evaluating 'asset.scales' when trying to set the background image, anyone knows why even if everything seems fine.

```
import { ImageBackground, StyleSheet } from 'react-native-web'
function WelcomePage() {
    return (<ImageBackground source={require('../assets/background.jpg')} style={{width: '100%', height: '100%'}} resizeMode="cover" >

            </ImageBackground>)
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    backGround: {
        flex: 1,
        width: '100%',
        height: '100%',
    }
})
export default WelcomePage
```

Answer (score 0):

You are using the wrong import for `ImageBackground`. Change your import to the following.

```js
import { ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
```

Compare this with the [documentation of react-native-web](https://necolas.github.io/react-native-web/docs/image-background/).